# arydshln stretches my vertical lines in tabular

Tags: tables, arydshln

The moment I put `arydshln` in the preamble, it messes up the boxes I drew around numbers. I'm trying to draw dotted lines in tables.

```
\documentclass[10pt, b5paper]{article}
\usepackage{ipaex-type1}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\restylefloat{figure}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt} 
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\geometry{b5paper, margin=0.5in}
\setCJKmainfont{MS Mincho} % for \rmfamily
\setCJKsansfont{CMU Serif} % for \sffamily
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} X\\ Y\\ Z\end{tabular}} &
  \multicolumn{11}{c|}{１Ａ・Ｂ・Ｃ【Handout】〈Part１〉} &
  誤答数 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{クラス} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}氏\\ 名\end{tabular}} &
  \multicolumn{8}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cline{2-3}
 &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
   &
  \multicolumn{8}{l|}{} &
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}  \vspace{-5mm}
※キーワードチェックをしましょう。\hspace{1cm}※答えは回答欄に記入しなさい\
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
   \begin{table}[h]
      \begin{tabular}{|m{0.15cm}|}
        \hline
     \\[-2.45ex]
        \textbf{1} \\[0.13ex]
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
次の動詞を過去形にしましょう。ただし，答えが２語以上あるものもあります。
\end{table}\\
```

[image: My box gets a saggy chin when I use arydshln]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code fragment compilable. Also reduce your document preamble to minimum, remove all package which are not relevant to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first time posting here. I'll try and edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I haven't CJK fonts, so in y MWE (Minimal Working Example) replace CJK text with dummy asci text. Doing this

- I didn't find any problem with `arydshln` package. It works as expected
- For coloring cell instead `colortbl` (which not work as expected) is better to use `[table]{xcolor}`
- table are poor populate, consequently is hard to redefine columns type (at least to I would change to `p` type
- use float `table` for making frame around number is very strange and error prone. Instead it is far more appropriate to use `\fbox`. Here is also not clear, what you like to achieve by this. You may find fonts which has numbers in boxes or in circles.

MWE, where i try to reproduce your table and framed number is:

```
\documentclass[10pt, b5paper]{article}
\usepackage[b5paper, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ipaex-type1}
%\usepackage{inputenc}
%\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{arydshln}
%\restylefloat{figure}
%\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
%\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
%\setCJKmainfont{MS Mincho} % for \rmfamily
%\setCJKsansfont{CMU Serif} % for \sffamily

\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht] % <---
\begin{tabular}{|p{2em}|l|l|>{\centering}p{2em}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} % <---
\hline
\multirow{3}{=}{X\\ Y\\ Z} % <---
    &   \multicolumn{11}{c|}{some CJK text%１Ａ・Ｂ・Ｃ【Handout】〈Part１〉
                        } & some CJK text   %誤答数 
    \\ \cline{2-13}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{some text} %クラス
        &   \multirow{2}{=}{\centering % <---
                            YY  \\  %氏
                            XX      %名
                           } 
            &   \multicolumn{8}{l|}{} 
                &   \multirow{2}{*}{} 
    \\ \cline{2-3}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{l|}{ } 
        &   &   \multicolumn{8}{l|}{ } 
                &    
    \\  \hdashline % <---
    \rowcolor{gray!30} % <---
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 % <--- added
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

some CJK text\hspace{1cm}some CJK text %※キーワードチェックをしましょう。\hspace{1cm}※答えは回答欄に記入しなさい\

\medskip
\fbox{\thead{1}}
some some CJK text % 次の動詞を過去形にしましょう。ただし，答えが２語以上あるものもあります。

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, activate your CJK text above MWE and then tell me, if it still works. For now, I don’t see why not.

Comment: Hi, why do have not used nicematrix package? ahahahahah. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano, because I'm old man and still find old package very useful :-). Of course, `nicematrix` is versatile and powerful package, but its evolving is faster than my ability to master it ;-) Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you an old man? Nooooooooo.....noooooo.. It is not true...You have also a young mind...:-)

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried and ended up with an error: Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \restylefloat

Comment: @n00bish, if you like to use `\restylefloat` you need to add `\usepackage{float}` to preamble. Since I didn't fint it in your MWE, I comment out this command (as a cause of error).

Comment: @Zarko You were absolutely right about fbox! That solved my problem! Thank you!

Comment: @n00bish, if my answer solve your problem(s) you may consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer) :-)

Comment: @Zarko Done! You're awesome!